# Blazor - add child content as Javascript code

Tags: javascript, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm looking to create a Blazor JavaScript component like this:

```
<BlazorJavaScript>
 <Code>

    if (10 <= 20) alert('hello');

 </Code>
</BlazorJavaScript>
```

So, the goal is to put Javascript code inside a  tag (not as an attribute).

I tried to use RenderFragment and string, but it seems I can only add XML / HTML content.

Is there a solution?

Comment: How are you going to use that thing inside `Code`? You will use it as an string? Or render it inside a `script` tag or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I expect to load it dynamically (It is something that I already do from the C# code, it works fine). But I'm looking to add a tag, it will be easier to read and manage. So, have a string is fine.

Comment: "I expect to load it dynamically" doesn't explain much, Is there any reason why you don't want to use it as an attribute?

Comment: Each component can have its own Javascript (We don't have to put it on the chtml file then). Why not an attribute, first because any " character will close the attribute, but also because the JS code can be very long.

Comment: '<' is a beginning of an HTML tag blazor throwing an exception 'Unclosed tag '' with no matching end tag.', so you can use @("<") apart from this are able to run your code in JavaScript?

Comment: It is an idea, but I really wish to put javascript without changing anything, like a <script> ... </script> HTML tag! To answer, yes I have a way to load JS dynamically, way easier than using JS Interop.

Comment: Is it possible to share your code, load JS dynamically? I was trying with JS interop.